# token product probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

There are 10 tokens in a box: 5 of them have number 2 on them, 3 of them have number 4 and 2 of them have number 8. If we take out a token 100 times (returning it into the box every time) what is the probability that the product of these tokens will be between $2^{160}$ and $2^{200}$?

I understand that I am supposed to use the normal distribution here and I have already found the possibility of each of these events (taking one number 2 token, or number 4 or number 8). The only thing I am missing is $p$ which I am supposed to use in this normal distribution. Any hints on how I can get that? thanks

Comment: "I am missing $p$.." What exactly do you mean with this $p$?

Comment: It is the probability I am supposed to use in normal distribution in order to find the probability that the product will be between $2^{160}$ and $2^{200}$.

Comment: probability of what event then?

Comment: that is actually what confuses me.. maybe I am using a completely wrong approach

Comment: We are dealing with iid random variables $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$. If $n$ is large and $\mathbb EY_1^2<\infty$ then you can apply the central limit theorem and the problem can be solved if you can find $\mathbb EY_1$ and $\text{Var}(Y_1)$. This is what you meet in my answer. If the $Y_1$ are Bernoulli then $\mathbb EY_1=P(Y_1=1)=p$. This can be the $p$ that wanders around in your thinking. In that situation the summation of the $Y_i$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$. But here things are different. No Bernoulli and no binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_i$ stands for the number that shows up at the $i$-th draw then you are asked to find or estimate the probability that $$2^{160}\leq\prod_{i=1}^{100}X_i\leq2^{200}$$ or equivalently$$160\leq\sum_{i=1}^{100}Y_i\leq200$$where $Y_{i}:=\log_{2}X_{i}$

If $\mu:=\mathbb EY_1$ and $\sigma^2=\text{Var}Y_i$ then you can write this as:$$\frac{160-100\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{100}}\leq Z:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{100}Y_i-100\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{100}}\leq\frac{200-100\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{100}}$$

Here according to the CLS the distribution of $Z$ is almost standard normal.

Comment: yes, I know how to get to there. what I don't know are $\mu$ and $\sigma$.. I was wondering how I can find those

Comment: $\mathbb EY_1=\frac5{10}\log_22+\frac3{10}\log_24+\frac2{10}\log_28=0.5+0.3\times2+0.2\times3$. Also find $\mathbb EY_1^2$ (and variance) like that.

Comment: I believe that $\mu = np$, where $n=100$, so shouldn't there be $160-\mu$ and $200-\mu$.. and when I get $\mu=1.7$, I can get from there that $p=0.017$. Is this correct?

Comment: The $\mu$ in my answer is not the same as the $\mu$ in your comment. Yours is the $100$-fold of mine. You are talking about $p$, but what $p$?..In some way my $\mu$ plays the role of your $p$. If you approach binomial distribution with normal then $p$ comes is as expectation of a Bernouilli variable. In my answer that place is taken by $\mathbb EY_1$ which is my $\mu$.

Comment: Don't know. I have not the disposal of tables, and don't like them. Maybe some one else can confirm or deny.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help, I understand your solution now

Comment: You are very welcome